# I can't die. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

I meet many people.

I treat them equal.

I can harvest grain the middle age way.

I always go on, I never stay.

I can't die.

Some believe I can fly.

Most people don't like me.

And thus try to fight me.

Most people don't want me to touch them.

Some mad people want me to rush them.

There is no proof that I exist.

But what I do can't be dismissed.

Who am I?

Comment: [John Donne](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44107/holy-sonnets-death-be-not-proud) would have disagreed with your title :-).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I think you might be

> [The Grim Reaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_(personification)) (Angel of Death)

I meet many people.
I treat them equal.

> Many people die every day, death comes equally for all

I can harvest grain the middle age way.

> The Reaper is often depicted as holding a large scythe.

I always go on, I never stay.
I can't die.

> Death itself cannot die.

Some believe I can fly.

> According to the Midrash, the Angel of Death was created by God on the first day. His dwelling is in heaven, whence he reaches earth in eight flights

Most People don't like me.

> Not many people want to die (meet the reaper)

And thus try to fight me.

> Many will try to avoid death for as long as possible

Most people don't want me to touch them.
Some mad people want me to rush them.

> Not sure but perhaps those with a deathwish.

There is no proof that I exist.

> This is just a personification based on belief.

But what I do cant be dismissed.

> Death is constantly observed

Who am I?

Comment: 100% what I thought.

Comment: damn! 2 minutes late :(

Comment: @ Flying_whale : anyway correct. plus your answer offers alternate ways to interpret the single lines.

Comment: That was an easy one!

Comment: Possibly the wrong place for this question but does the sentence "According to the Midrash, the Angel of Death was created by God on the first day." imply that God created the concept of death before he punished Adam and Eve with death for eating the forbidden fruit?

Comment: @Parrotmaster https://christianity.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Parrotmaster or possibly judaism.stackexchange.com (midrash is a Jewish rather than a Christian thing).

Comment: I would of answered Death.

Comment: "Death itself cannot die" hmm. If death will die, it will play a game with itself. Some singleplayer one?

Answer (score 29):

Who am I?

> You are Time.

I meet many people.

> Time meets everyone, every time

I treat them equal.

> Time never act differently with anyone.

I can harvest grain the middle age way.

> Do not know. Actually, do not understood what that mean.

I always go on, I never stay.

> Obviously; isn't it?

I can't die.

> Time never *start* and never it does *end*. In other words, it never born and never die. By the way, quantum physics does not agree with me. It says, time was *created* while big bang; before that, there was no time. Also that time will end when entire universe will again convert in small dot of energy. Anyway, we are not discussing physics here.

Some believe I can fly.

> Time *flies* so quickly when we are happy, with loved ones.

Most people don't like me.

> Those who are in bad conditions, difficulties do not like *current* time. They want it to be passed quickly.

And thus try to fight me.

> As said above, they do not like it. They try hard (fight) to get out of bad times.

Most people don't want me to touch them.

> Age? Most people like to live young (or kid) all the time.

Some mad people want me to rush them.

> Not sure but some people like to grow up quickly. Or when in bad time, people want good time should come quickly.

There is no proof that I exist.

> Time is not visible, not touchable, not smell-able. One cannot prove the existence of time. Physics does; but again, we are not discussing in terms of physics.

But what I do can't be dismissed.

> Though we cannot prove its existence, we see the incidents happening around us and the history. We cannot dismiss these things and those prove the existence of time.

Comment: Very good. I actually didnt think of time as an answer, but I'd definitely accept it the way you presented it. Too bad one can just accept one answer. +1 anyway.

Comment: I actually thought the same thing, for the grain part something along the lines of https://xkcd.com/926/ .

Comment: In the Middle Age, grain was harvested using a scythe. Hence why I agree with the most voted answer. But I guessed time, too.

Comment: @WAF - The question reminded me also of that xkcd. In wake of that, it seems to be a more plausible answer than then one currently accepted.

Comment: Not really sure how people arrive at any other conclusion than the answer is time. The accepted answer of "death itself" doesn't still well with me. Death can not fly, and as for no proof that i exist - A quick image search of the term "dead hamster" should settle that one.

Comment: Time does fly! :D

Comment: Does time actually treat everyone equally tho? What about special relativity (e.g. objects that move very fast)? You did say you are not talking to physics in some of your answers, but I don't think we can just ignore physics...

Answer (score 13):

Are you

> the Grim Reaper

because

I meet many people.
I treat them equal.

> everybody dies

I can harvest grain the middle age way.

> you can die young

I always go on, I never stay.

> death's fast most of the time

I can't die.

> death can't die, people will always be dying

Some believe I can fly.

> some representations show the Grim Reaper flying above the floor

Most people don't like me.
And thus try to fight me.

> people don't want to die, and heal themselves when sick

Most people don't want me to touch them.
Some mad people want me to rush them.

> again, most people don't wanna die but some jackasses don't care doing potentially lethal stuff

There is no proof that I exist.

> Death sure exists, but the Grim Reaper as shown in popular believes don't

But what I do can't be dismissed.

> you can't revive people

Comment: For "I can harvest grain the middle age way", the Grim Reaper is often depicted wielding a scythe, which was used to harvest wheat and other crops.

Answer (score 5):

I meet many people.

> I am everywhere all time at shopping malls and such.

I treat them equal.

> And I give them equal treats.

I can harvest grain the middle age way.

> I can but I don't because my belly gets in the way.

I always go on, I never stay.

> Dropping my presents along the way

I can't die.

> or children would cry.

Some believe I can fly.

> And I do with a little help from 8 tiny reindeer.

Most people don't like me.

> Scrooge and many adults.

And thus try to fight me.

> They say I don't exist

Most people don't want me to touch them.

> They think I am a drunk from the shopping mall.

Some mad people want me to rush them.

> Everyone that believes wants their presents in a hurry!!

There is no proof that I exist.

> Let's keep it that way, Shall we!!

But what I do can't be dismissed.

> A merry Christmas to all and to all a good night.

Who am I?

> Santa Claus

Comment: Thanks for the edit !!! Just another way to look at it. ~_-

Comment: Well, one more way to interpret my poem in a senseful way : ) And its so far away from the 0-8-15 interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

**Who am I?**

> Windows XP

I meet many people.

> Many people are still using it.

I treat them equal.

> Software is always "the same."

I can harvest grain the middle age way.

> Many farm computers run on Win XP.
>  probably better explanation by Criggie:
>  *"Isn't a common background image that of an unripe grain field? Which can be harvested the middle age way ?"*

I always go on, I never stay.

> Digital data can travel very fast - it is unlikely for setups to last for a long time.

I can't die.

> There will always be a copy of XP on someone's disk.

Some believe I can fly.

> XP sort of "flies" when sent as a file through satellites.

Most People don't like me.

> XP is far too old and hated by many people, mostly developers, but also others messing around with users unable to open files or similar situations.

And thus try to fight me.

> Especially Microsoft itself, but also devs and others try to convince users to move away from XP.

Most people don't want me to touch them.

> Many people prefer to not have a try on it, reasons mentioned above.

Some mad people want me to rush them.

> There are always some retro fans...

There is no proof that I exist.

> It's digital - there's nothing "solid" you can really touch. Conspiracy theorists will always claim that it doesn't exist.

But what I do cant be dismissed.

> Still, many systems rely on this outdated OS.

Some points only fit partially however...

Comment: Isn't a common background image that of an unripe grain field?  Which can be harvested the middle age way ?

Comment: @Criggie : Good point ! Basically I don't see much more than grass, but edited !

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

> **the Wind**

**I meet many people.**

> the wind travels the world

**I treat them equal.**

> the wind is no respector of persons

**I can harvest grain the middle age way.**

> grain was beaten then tossed into the air to separate the grain from the chaff

**I always go on, I never stay.**

> wind cannot be stationary. It is a movement that causes it to exist

**I can't die.**

> the wind is and always will be. It is ageless

**Some believe I can fly.**

> The expression -"fly like the wind"

**Most people don't like me.**

> in the majority of the world the wind is cold and is unliked.

**And thus try to fight me.**

> sailors and planes "fight against the wind"

**Most people don't want me to touch them.**

> People wear layers and coats to avoid having the wind touch them

**Some mad people want me to rush them.**

> this relates to another phrase associated with high octane or adrenaline fueled activities. These "Mad" people wish to feel the "rush of the wind"

**There is no proof that I exist.**

> How can you prove that the wind exists? you can argue that it is not a physical thing but a phenomenon. Air exists and it moves but does wind really exist? Where does wind go when it stops?

**But what I do can't be dismissed.**

> There is no question that towns can be leveled, boats can be pushed across oceans and kites can be lifted into the sky by Wind.

**Who am I?**

> **The Wind**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**) Great first answer - please note that here we put answers in spoilers (>!) to preserve the mystery for other would-be solvers.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I am afraid this is a duplicate answer after 4 hours.

Comment: This answer explains most verses very well, but just like several other answers, struggles with the verse before the last one ("There is no proof that I exist."). However, the explanation for the 3rd verse ("I can harvest grain the middle age way.") is one of the best in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I meet many people.

> You appear everywhere in the world, at least one time per year

I treat them equal.

> Doesn't matter who they are, they all meet you and received the same treatment, some people are more prepared for you then others.

I can harvest grain the middle age way.

> You can destroy crops before they are ready

I always go on, I never stay.

> You always go away after some time

I can't die.

> You just come back

Some believe I can fly.

> Through the wind

Most people don't like me.

> People normally hate you

And thus try to fight me.

> With clothes and heaters

Most people don't want me to touch them.

> They try to protect themselves from you

Some mad people want me to rush them.

> But yet, some people love to feel you against their skin

There is no proof that I exist.

But what I do can't be dismissed.

Who am I?

> You could be "Cold". Cold is the absence of heat, not a real physical thing, but lack of one, although we can feel it.

Comment: This answer fits in very well with most of the verses. It only struggles explaining the last two ones but several answers do.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> Time

I meet many people.

> Clock towers

I treat them equal.

> Time treat everyone equal

I can harvest grain the middle age way.

I always go on, I never stay.

> Time keeps on moving

I can't die.

> Time can't die

Some believe I can fly.

> Time flies

Most people don't like me.

> Lazy people don't like time

And thus try to fight me.

> Lazy people compete with time in the last minute

Most people don't want me to touch them.

Some mad people want me to rush them.

> By setting alarm?

There is no proof that I exist.

> Man made?

But what I do can't be dismissed.

> Time can't be dismissed. Alarm can be lol.

Who am I?

> Time

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I am afraid this is a duplicate answer.

Comment: @AhmedAshour Lol. Apparently. I did'nt see other answers :).

Comment: The conclusion is the same, but the explanations do differ, so I would not call this a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I meet many people.

> It is everywhere and everywhere in the world

I treat them equal.

> It flings everything in her way

I can harvest grain the middle age way.

> Sometimes it is strong and indeed it can harvest grain

I always go on, I never stay.

> It is motile and always moves on

I can't die.

> It is not human, so It can not die

Some believe I can fly.

> When it is too strong it can cause damage and because of its activity that sweeps everything in its way it seems to fly

Most people don't like me.

And thus try to fight me.

Most people don't want me to touch them.

Some mad people want me to rush them.

> People think that if they are thin and light It can swing them

There is no proof that I exist.

> It is not real

But what I do can't be dismissed.

> Without it a lot of actions in nature will be stopped

Who am I?

> Wind

Answer (score -1):

**Who am I?**

> ❤ Love

I meet many people.

> Many people fall in love.

I treat them equal.

> Nobody has control about this underlying feeling.

I can harvest grain the middle age way.

> "Harvesting grain the middle age way" can be interpreted as harvesting something before it is fully mature. Love does this often. Young people fall in love before they even really understand what it is, which often brings up confusion.

I always go on, I never stay.

> Love is often described as something that is only temporary and can hardly last for long. As Michel de Montaigne puts it : "If you press me to say why I loved him, I can say no more than because he was he, and I was I." The conclusion is simple : people change, as do their feelings for each other. Love is one of the most disappointing feelings; think of all the dramas and sad songs. Misconduct & co. are (sadly) very common things. Another de Montaigne quote concerning the same subject(where he actually criticizes love) : *"If there is such a thing as a good marriage, it is because it resembles friendship rather than love."*

I can't die.

> Emotions can't die.

Some believe I can fly.

> There are tons of theories and myths concerning the reasons of love. Some also involve flying. There are also several metaphors; love makes you "fly", love "flies" to you, etc.

Most People don't like me.

> Note this is just the author's perspective. But love is a complicated subject, and not anybody can deal with it very well. Thus, it may be possible that there are many people who already got afraid of love - being unable to come together with their dream partner, being divorced, etc.

And thus try to fight me.

> It is common that people - especially when experiencing love for the first time in their life - try to fight against their feelings.

Most people don't want me to touch them.

> For the same reasons, many people prefer not to get to meet love, being unsure what it really is and whether they would like it.

Some mad people want me to rush them.

> Some people are mature very early in their lives, and don't want love to come slowly to them. They can be very annoying and harassing; look at #metoo. The maddest ones even go as far as raping others.

There is no proof that I exist.

> It's impossible to (scientifically) check whether two people "love" each other, what their feelings for their partner are. Many people pretend to love their partners even if it's not the case (anymore), others are hiding their love from the public.

But what I do cant be dismissed.

> It is impossible to reject your feelings. Just let them be part of you. But still, make sure that your reasoning stays in control. And please try not to be one of the mad ones.